# Prove for sets $A,B,C$ that $A\times (B\setminus C) = A\times B \setminus A\times C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to solve it as follows:
We have 
$$(x,y) \in A\times (B \setminus C) \iff$$
$$x \in A \ \text{and} \  y \in (B \setminus C) \iff$$
$$(x \in  A) \ \text{and} \  (y \in  B \ \text{and} \  y \notin C) $$
$$(x \in A) \ \text{and} \ (y \in B \ \text{or} \ y \in C')$$
$$[(x \in A) \ \text{and} \ (y \in  B)]\ \text{or}\ [(x \in A) \ \text{and} \ (y \in C')] $$
$$(x,y)  \in A\times B \ \text{or}\ [(x \in A) \ \text{and} \ (y \in C')]$$ 
But beyond this not able to proceed.

Comment: Your first step where you switched to “or” instead of “and” is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x,y)\in A\times (B\setminus C) \Longleftrightarrow x\in A\wedge y\in B\setminus C$

$\Longleftrightarrow x\in A\wedge (y\in B\wedge y\not\in C)$

$\Longleftrightarrow (x\in A\wedge y\in B)\wedge (x\in A\wedge y\not\in C)$

$\Longleftrightarrow (x,y)\in A\times B \wedge (x,y)\not\in A\times C$

$\Longleftrightarrow (x,y)\in A\times B \setminus A\times C$.

Comment: I have understood the mistake made by me. Thanks sir.